# ElasticSearch server not starting

Tags: elasticsearch, server, nosql

I searched for hours but still couldn't find the reason behind it.

following are the logs I get while running command:

```
sudo bash -x /etc/init.d/elasticsearch start
```

Logs:

```
+ PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin
+ NAME=elasticsearch
+ DESC='Elasticsearch Server'
+ DEFAULT=/etc/default/elasticsearch
++ id -u
+ '[' 0 -ne 0 ']'
+ . /lib/lsb/init-functions
+++ run-parts --lsbsysinit --list /lib/lsb/init-functions.d
++ for hook in '$(run-parts --lsbsysinit --list /lib/lsb/init-functions.d 2>/dev/null)'
++ '[' -r /lib/lsb/init-functions.d/01-upstart-lsb ']'
++ . /lib/lsb/init-functions.d/01-upstart-lsb
+++ unset UPSTART_SESSION
+++ _RC_SCRIPT=/etc/init.d/elasticsearch
+++ '[' -r /etc/init//etc/init.d/elasticsearch.conf ']'
+++ _UPSTART_JOB=elasticsearch
+++ '[' -r /etc/init/elasticsearch.conf ']'
++ for hook in '$(run-parts --lsbsysinit --list /lib/lsb/init-functions.d 2>/dev/null)'
++ '[' -r /lib/lsb/init-functions.d/20-left-info-blocks ']'
++ . /lib/lsb/init-functions.d/20-left-info-blocks
++ for hook in '$(run-parts --lsbsysinit --list /lib/lsb/init-functions.d 2>/dev/null)'
++ '[' -r /lib/lsb/init-functions.d/50-ubuntu-logging ']'
++ . /lib/lsb/init-functions.d/50-ubuntu-logging
+++ LOG_DAEMON_MSG=
++ FANCYTTY=
++ '[' -e /etc/lsb-base-logging.sh ']'
++ true
+ '[' -r /etc/default/rcS ']'
+ . /etc/default/rcS
++ UTC=yes
+ ES_USER=elasticsearch
+ ES_GROUP=elasticsearch
+ ES_HOME=/usr/share/elasticsearch
+ MAX_OPEN_FILES=65536
+ LOG_DIR=/var/log/elasticsearch
+ DATA_DIR=/var/lib/elasticsearch
+ CONF_DIR=/etc/elasticsearch
+ MAX_MAP_COUNT=262144
+ PID_DIR=/var/run/elasticsearch
+ '[' -f /etc/default/elasticsearch ']'
+ . /etc/default/elasticsearch
++ ES_STARTUP_SLEEP_TIME=5
+ '[' '!' -z '' ']'
+ PID_FILE=/var/run/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.pid
+ DAEMON=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch
+ DAEMON_OPTS='-d -p /var/run/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.pid --default.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch --default.path.logs=/var/log/elasticsearch --default.path.data=/var/lib/elasticsearch --default.path.conf=/etc/elasticsearch'
+ export ES_HEAP_SIZE
+ export ES_HEAP_NEWSIZE
+ export ES_DIRECT_SIZE
+ export ES_JAVA_OPTS
+ export ES_GC_LOG_FILE
+ export JAVA_HOME
+ export ES_INCLUDE
+ test -x /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch
+ case "$1" in
+ checkJava
+ '[' -x /bin/java ']'
++ which java
+ JAVA=/usr/bin/java
+ '[' '!' -x /usr/bin/java ']'
+ '[' -n '' -a -z '' ']'
+ log_daemon_msg 'Starting Elasticsearch Server'
+ '[' -z 'Starting Elasticsearch Server' ']'
+ log_use_fancy_output
+ TPUT=/usr/bin/tput
+ EXPR=/usr/bin/expr
+ '[' -t 1 ']'
+ '[' xxterm '!=' x ']'
+ '[' xxterm '!=' xdumb ']'
+ '[' -x /usr/bin/tput ']'
+ '[' -x /usr/bin/expr ']'
+ /usr/bin/tput hpa 60
+ /usr/bin/tput setaf 1
+ '[' -z ']'
+ FANCYTTY=1
+ case "$FANCYTTY" in
+ true
+ /usr/bin/tput xenl
++ /usr/bin/tput cols
+ COLS=80
+ '[' 80 ']'
+ '[' 80 -gt 6 ']'
++ /usr/bin/expr 80 - 7
+ COL=73
+ log_use_plymouth
+ '[' n = y ']'
+ plymouth --ping
+ printf ' * Starting Elasticsearch Server       '
 * Starting Elasticsearch Server       ++ /usr/bin/expr 80 - 1
+ /usr/bin/tput hpa 79
                                                                               + printf ' '
 ++ pidofproc -p /var/run/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.pid elasticsearch
++ local pidfile base status specified pid OPTIND
++ pidfile=
++ specified=
++ OPTIND=1
++ getopts p: opt
++ case "$opt" in
++ pidfile=/var/run/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.pid
++ specified=specified
++ getopts p: opt
++ shift 2
++ '[' 1 -ne 1 ']'
++ base=elasticsearch
++ '[' '!' specified ']'
++ '[' -n /var/run/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.pid -a -r /var/run/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.pid ']'
++ read pid
++ '[' -n '' ']'
++ '[' -n specified ']'
++ '[' -e /var/run/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.pid -a '!' -r /var/run/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.pid ']'
++ return 3
+ pid=
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ mkdir -p /var/log/elasticsearch /var/lib/elasticsearch
+ chown elasticsearch:elasticsearch /var/log/elasticsearch /var/lib/elasticsearch
+ '[' -n /var/run/elasticsearch ']'
+ '[' '!' -e /var/run/elasticsearch ']'
+ '[' -n /var/run/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.pid ']'
+ '[' '!' -e /var/run/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.pid ']'
+ '[' -n 65536 ']'
+ ulimit -n 65536
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ '[' -n 262144 -a -f /proc/sys/vm/max_map_count ']'
+ sysctl -q -w vm.max_map_count=262144
+ start-stop-daemon -d /usr/share/elasticsearch --start -b --user elasticsearch -c elasticsearch --pidfile /var/run/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.pid --exec /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -- -d -p /var/run/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.pid --default.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch --default.path.logs=/var/log/elasticsearch --default.path.data=/var/lib/elasticsearch --default.path.conf=/etc/elasticsearch
+ return=0
+ '[' 0 -eq 0 ']'
+ i=0
+ timeout=10
+ sleep 1
+ i=1
+ '[' 1 -gt 10 ']'
+ sleep 1
+ i=2
+ '[' 2 -gt 10 ']'
+ sleep 1
+ i=3
+ '[' 3 -gt 10 ']'
+ sleep 1
+ i=4
+ '[' 4 -gt 10 ']'
+ sleep 1
+ i=5
+ '[' 5 -gt 10 ']'
+ sleep 1
+ i=6
+ '[' 6 -gt 10 ']'
+ sleep 1
+ i=7
+ '[' 7 -gt 10 ']'
+ sleep 1
+ i=8
+ '[' 8 -gt 10 ']'
+ sleep 1
+ i=9
+ '[' 9 -gt 10 ']'
+ sleep 1
+ i=10
+ '[' 10 -gt 10 ']'
+ sleep 1
+ i=11
+ '[' 11 -gt 10 ']'
+ log_end_msg 1
+ '[' -z 1 ']'
+ '[' 73 ']'
+ '[' -x /usr/bin/tput ']'
+ log_use_plymouth
+ '[' n = y ']'
+ plymouth --ping
+ printf '\r'
+ /usr/bin/tput hpa 73
                                                                         + '[' 1 -eq 0 ']'
+ printf '['
[+ /usr/bin/tput setaf 1
+ printf fail
fail+ /usr/bin/tput op
+ echo ']'
]
+ return 1
+ exit 1
```

I am using elastic search version 2.4.1. There are no logs in /var/log/elasticsearch

And I have also tried following sol.

[elasticsearch can't start service in ubuntu 15.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35232521/elasticsearch-cant-start-service-in-ubuntu-15-10)

Comment: Same error here. When running without `set -x` I get `sysctl: setting key "vm.max_map_count": Read-only file system`.

Answer (score 1):

One reason for the error is if the java heap size is set to higher than the available system memory

Update the elastcsearch startup script to set the elasticsearch heap memory settings:

`/etc/init.d/elasticsearch
ES_HEAP_SIZE=2g`